# Must-have features for F/OSS SQL analyzer/optimizer

Tags: mysql, query-analyzer

I like [MySQL's Query Analyzer](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/query.html)...but not the price tag.  I think I can write something myself to do analysis on slow query logs, indexes, table status fields, etc. and offer it as an alternative, F/OSS solution.

What would be your top-requested features for such a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Freeware
- Scalable (multi computer database)
- Multiprocess
- Query Comparer among databases (transfer schema to eg: Postgresql then run the query there too)
- Import txt/sql/server logs and pick up queries from the log for analyze
- Analyze w simulation of server load / query analyzer during ~duress (low memory, low tmp, high processor usage)
- Analyze under different SQL server configuration profiles (auto change config file, restart etc...)
- A tunnel script file (php,cgi) to run the analyze on a server without public connection access.

Answer (score 0):

- Ability to manage multiple connections to different servers / profiles

Maybe nice to have:

- "On the fly" mode: Throw in a table declaration and a query, software creates table in temporary database and explains query

Answer (score 0):

Maatkit's [mk-query-digest](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-digest.html) does most of this and is open-source. It's not a GUI, but I find the data more useful and flexible than the query analyzer. Using the tcpdump mode provides much of what query analyzer provides without the proxy overhead.

Perhaps looking at integrating Maatkit or at least Maatkit's ideas into a GUI would be useful.